# Reading text files paths with the same order of them in the directory in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have text files located in a directory. The text files are ordered by name in that directory. I want to read the paths of those text files with same order (by name) into array. I'm using the following code :

```
string[] textpaths = Directory.GetFiles(filepath + "\\source", "*",    
SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But the array of paths I got doesn't has the same directory order. Could any one help please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you can't read path in order of name using in-build functions. write you own...first buffer than sort

Comment: In which order, in alphabatical ?? use sort by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which order, you can always sort the files using simple linq queries.

```
string[] textpaths = Directory.GetFiles(filepath + "\\source", "*",    
SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray();
```

Alternatively you can you [DiretoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx) to sort it using other attributes.

```
// Sort by full name  
string[] textpaths = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\test").GetFiles("*",    
SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(x=>x.FullName).Select(x=>x.FullName).ToArray();  

// Sort by creation time  
string[] textpaths = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\test").GetFiles("*",    
SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(x=>x.CreationTime).Select(x=>x.FullName).ToArray();
```

Comment: @ Tilak, i tried the first code but it doesn't work for the full path. I will try using DirectoryInfo one ..

Comment: updated code. Check now, replace c:\\test with your top level directory.

Answer (score 2):

Then order them, what's the big deal?

```
string[] textpaths = Directory.GetFiles(
    filepath + "\\source", 
    "*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories
    ).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: I believe that `Directory.GetFiles` returning strings, not array of `FileInfo` objects

Comment: @ SomebodyYouKnow. I tried your code, but there is a red line under the "Name".. why ??

Answer (score 2):

Simply sort the resulting array :

```
IEnumerable<string> textpaths = Directory.GetFiles(
    Path.Combine(filepath, "source"), 
    "*",    
    SearchOption.AllDirectories
    ).OrderBy(f=>f);
```

You can also use this syntax, depending on your personal preference :

```
var textPaths = from file in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(filepath, "source"), "*",  SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                order by file
                select file;
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net does not use sorting which you have applied in your file manager. But you can order files manually:

```
IEnumerable<string> orderedPaths = textpaths.OrderBy(path => path);
```

Or in single query:

```
IEnumerable<string> orderedPaths = 
   Directory.GetFiles(filepath + "\\source", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .OrderBy(path => path);
```

Answer (score 0):

sort the array afterwards using linq

Comment: very useless answer, when other give the one-line answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string[] textpaths = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(filepath + "\\source", "*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);  
Array.Sort(textpaths , delegate(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2) {
return f1.Name.CompareTo(f2.Name);
});
```

Comment: Should be DirectoryInfo.GetFiles

Comment: @Tilak: with the precision that `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` is not static. That means that you will have to create a `var di = new DirectoryInfo(wheretolook);` before enumerating the files `di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Comment: @Qaesar: look in my comment, I've the correct code when using DirectoryInfo